# Firebase Android: Join and return data sequentially

Tags: java, android, firebase, join

I'm developing group chat with firebase.
Firebase's database looks like this:
`root
  messages
    groupId
      -uuid
        content: "hello"
        type: "message"
        sender_id: "uuid"
      -uuid
        content: "hello"
        type: "plan"
        sender_id: "uuid"
        plan_id "uuid"
  users
    uuid
      name: "UserName"
      avatar: "url" 
  plans
    uuid:
      content: "blah blah"
      location: "Blah blah"`

For example: I want to display the messages into RecyclerView, to display user's info, i'll perform another operation. and if message's `type` is plan, i'll perform one more operations.
I know it's normal to denormalize data, but i need to stick with database design.
I use `ChildEventListener` to get message, then read `users` with `SingleValueEvent` and read `plans` with `SingleValueEvent` if `type` is plan.
This is how i get data from firebase .

```
mDatabaseReference.child(FIREBASE_CHILD_MESSAGE)
    .child(String.valueOf(mConversation.getId()))
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(mLimit)
    .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                    String userPath = "users/" + message.getSenderId();
                    mDatabaseReference.child(userPath)
                            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                                    message.setSenderAvatar(user.getAvatar());
                                    message.setSenderName(user.getName());
                                    if (message.getMessageType() == Message.PLAN) {
                                        mDatabaseReference.child(FIREBASE_CHILD_PLANS)
                                                .child(message.getReferenceId())
                                                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                        Plan plan = dataSnapshot.getValue(Plan.class);
                                                        message.setPlan(plan);
                                                        if (getMvpView() != null) {
                                                            getMvpView().showAddedMessage(message);
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                    }
                                                });
                                    } else {
                                        getMvpView().showAddedMessage(message);
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });

                }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                //TODO
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //TODO
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
    });
```

The correct order should be from 1 to 15. but it isn't if the message type is plan and i need one more read operations.
`message 1
message 2
message 3
message 4
message 6
message 7
message 8
message 10
message 11
message 12
message 14
message 15
message 5 //plan
message 9 //plan
message 13 //plan`

Currently, i'm using MVP, and it's better to read all data from Presenter, and send it to View. So my question is how can i get results back with correct order?

Comment: Would please share the recyclerView code with view ?

Comment: It's pretty long because i have many viewholder (incoming, outcoming for each message, plan, date), but it's just normal recyclerview adapter with `SortedList`.

Comment: @quanlt To increase your chances of getting help, create a separate [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That helps you isolate the problem and reduces the code you need to share (and consequently that we need to read in order to help).

Comment: The reordering of the messages in your adapter sounds like a potential source of many problems. Can't you use a query to retrieve the messages in the correct order?

Comment: I've just updated the question to focus on my problem. Thank you for your help @FrankvanPuffelen. If i send message offline, and connect to the network, the order of message in recyclerview is wrong. so i need to reorder it again. But it should be an another question :)

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the problem, but I'm guessing the problem comes from adding the message to the view too late. If the order needs to come from the original query, you need to add the items immediately on `onChildAdded` and fill in the missing data later as it comes in. If this doesn't help you solve the problem, please reproduce the code in a minimum standalone code piece and then share both that code and the actual JSON (which you can get by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data)).